# C# MVC send obect via JQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, object, model-view-controller

despite I dug into stackoverflow and a lot of documentation, I am stuck on that:
I am not able to send an object via jquery ajax to a c# mvc application. Always the values of attributes of the order I return in the controller seems empty.

Thanks for any help!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function Order()
{
    this.Partner;
    this.OrderID;
    this.TypeOfOrder;
    this.SubmittedBy;
    this.CompanyID;
    this.CompanyName;
}

jQuery('button[type="submit"]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var order = new Order();
    order.Partner = "ABC",
    order.OrderID = "123";
    order.TypeOfOrder = "Website";

    console.log(order);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/my-route",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: order,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        }
    });
})
```

**C# Model**

```
public class Order
{
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfOrder { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

**C# Controller**

```
// POST my-route
[HttpPost]
public Order Post(Order order)
{
    return order;
}
```

**CONSOLE**

[image]

Comment: You need to remove `contentType: "application/json",` (either that or you need to use `data: JSON.stringify(order),`)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your method signature to include [FromBody]

so: public Order Post([FromBody]Order order)

Comment: Nope, I tried [FromBody] and the result from controller is undefined. I tried also [FromForm] and the result is an object with empty attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove content type in ajax call. It will look like this.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/my-route",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: order,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        console.log("ERROR!");
    }
});
```

ajax will default set content type.

Answer (score 0):

- Just remove dataType and contentType from code as given below function.
- Url should be "**/ControllerName/MethodName**" i have checked it in my system with 
  controller name and its working fine.

  `jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "/controllerName/methodName",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: order,
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                  },
                  failure: function (response) {
                      console.log("ERROR!");
                  }
              });`